Adjusting the margins in TOC and local TOC
I'm preparing a complex document with many local TOCs. Unfortunately, there are strict restrictions on the document format. So, I can’t adjust the left indentation of the first character of the second line in TOC, which is part of the local TOC.
It is necessary that the second line in TOC is aligned with the first.

MWE:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[
width=210.00mm,
height=297.00mm,
left=30.00mm,
right=15.00mm,
top=20.00mm,
bottom=20.00mm]
{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7} % уровень нумерации

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\hspace{\parindent}\bfseries}{\thechapter\quad}{0mm}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0mm}{-1.5em}{1em}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\hspace{\parindent}\bfseries}{\thesection\quad}{0mm}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{\baselineskip}{0mm}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\hspace{\parindent}\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0mm}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0mm}{\baselineskip}{0mm}

% main toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

% local toc
\titlecontents{psection}[0pt]{}{\contentslabel{0}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    Main table of contents
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Section 1.1 Lorem ipsum dolor}
    \section{Section 1.2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
        mauris.}
    \section{Section 1.3 Lorem ipsum dolor}
    \lipsum[1]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{New book}
    \begin{center}
        Book 1. Title
    \end{center}
    Local table of contents
    \startcontents[annex]
    \printcontents[annex]{p}{1}{}
    \vskip 2em
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annex 1. Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.}
    
    Some title of Annex 1.1\\
    \lipsum[1]\\
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annex 2. Lipsum is a LATEX package that produces dummy text to be used in test documents or examples.}
    
    Some title of Annex 1.2\\
    \lipsum[1]\\


\end{document}

How can this be fixed?
Thanks!

Welcome to TeX.SX!
